# Kubernetes init container issue with environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to add a init container to a deployment, but I can´t make the env vars work for some reason.

Just to illustrate, this is what I am trying:

```
initContainers:
    - name: init-db
      image: mysql:5.7
      env:
        - name: TEST
          value: nada
      args: ["echo", "${TEST}"]
```

But no matter what I do, the env vars doesn´t work, the `echo` always returns `${TEST}` instead of `nada`

Any hint?

Comment: variable substitution is done by the shell. Run the command in a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments and other answer mentioned you need to use shell for ENV substitution properly. therefore, replace the line

`args: ["echo", "${TEST}"]` in you code to

`command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo ${TEST}']`

[Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a shell in order to do ENV var substitution properly. For example:

```
initContainers:
    - name: init-db
      image: mysql:5.7
      env:
        - name: TEST
          value: nada
      command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - echo "${TEST}"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Kubernetes official documentation, you need to use **parentheses** `$(TEST)` for the variable to be expanded in the command or args field. I had an error using brackets because the env vars were not properly expanded on args. Working example:

```
initContainers:
  - name: my-container
    image: 'my-image'
    envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: my-config
    args:
      - '-path=/$(MY_ENV_VAR)'
```

[Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#use-environment-variables-to-define-arguments)